# Find documents in MongoDB where each value in array of subdocuments is less than param

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 'Patients' and 'Visits.'  I would like to find the all the patients who have not had a visit in the last month.  I am using mongoose.
Here are my schemas:

```
var VisitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    patient: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'patients'},
    created: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now
    }
});
var PatientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    visits: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'visits'}]
});
```

I would like to be able to do something like...

```
PatientModel.find({"visits.created": {$not: {$gt: monthAgo} }, err, result)
```

I have thought about maintaining a field in the Patient model to keep track of the latest visit.  Would this be a better approach?  If so, what would be the best way to maintain such a field, as visits are added, updated, and deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all patients have had at least one visit you could query the visits collection using an [aggregate pipeline](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate) (necessary for grouping):

```
 VisitModel.aggregate() // Make an aggregate pipeline
 .sort({created: -1}) // Reverse sort by created date (latest to oldest)
 .group({_id: '$patient', lastVisit: {$first: '$created'}}) // get latest visit and project new objects
 .match({lastVisit: {$gt: monthAgo}}) // only show patients with lastVisit greater than a month ago
 .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

This will result in an array of POJOs that represent the IDs for the patient and the date of their last visit.

Comment: Perfect.  Another complication: let's say I only want to find patients that have a field 'status' that is 'active'?

Comment: `VisitModel.aggregate([
                {$group: {_id:'$patient', recent:{$max:'$created'}}},                                      
                {$match: {recent:{$lte: timeago}}},
                {$sort: {recent: -1}},
                {$project: {_id:0, patient: '$_id', recent: '$recent'}}
            ], 
            (err, result)=>{
                if(err) return this.returnErr(err);
                PatientModel.populate(result, {path: "patient"}, (err, result)=>{
                    this.returnResult(err, result) 
                });                
            }
        );`